# click the ''Back to Top" button (scrollTop) multiple times issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, scrolltop

I have noticed that if i click the ''Back to Top" button multiple times and then you try to scroll down it causes the window to keep scrolling back to the top. Any idea how to stop this happening anyone?

my code is:

```
<a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

        $(window).scroll(function(){
    $("html, body").stop();
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
            }
        }); 
        $.clicked = false;
        if ($.clicked == false){
        $('.scrollup').click(function(){
        $.clicked = true;
            $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
            return false;
        });
       }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said you click multiple time so event will be fired mulitple times so you need to stop animation function,

So edit your code as below,

```
$("html, body").stop().animate(
 --------------^^^^^^^^----
```

OR edit code for scroll

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $("html, body").stop();
```

Comment: Hello @DipeshParmar thanks for help! the first code do the job. but if i insert the second code it make the scroll move only at one pixel up when i click on the button. but if use the code without the second code you share it still make some issue... *** you can see my original code i have edit as you suggested ***

Comment: @need-help sorry for my bad i place `also` in place of `OR` you can do this in either way .

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
        $('button').hide();
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) { // If page is scrolled more than 50px
                $('#return-to-top').fadeIn(200); // Fade in the arrow
            } else {
                $('#return-to-top').fadeOut(200); // Else fade out the arrow
            }
        });
        $('#return-to-top').click(function() { // When arrow is clicked
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0 // Scroll to top of body
            }, 500);
        });
    });
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue.

I just solved it with a simple check:

```
$('.scrollup').click(function(){
    if ($(document).scrollTop() != 0) {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
    }
    return false;
});
```

The problem, as already mentioned, is the click event firing multiple times. Because handling the event itself didn't work for me, I just tried to check if the current scroll value/position is already where I want it to be, et voilà: The weird behaviour vanished! :)